# How to print every coords from a to b (coordinates)

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how i can print, every x, y coordinates, from place a to place b.

For exapmple:

```js
//Map 8x4
var map = {
  col: `
     00000000
     00111100
     00111100
     00000000
    `
}

var a = {
  x: 21,
  y: 21
}

var b = {
  x: 26,
  y: 21
}

function generateTrack(a, b) {
  //console.log({x: 22, y: 21});
  //console.log({x: 23, y: 21});
  //console.log({x: 24, y: 22});
  //console.log({x: 25, y: 21});
}

generateTrack(a, b);
```

As you can see i have a map 8x4, and map collision are set like i showed you in the object, "1" means you can't walk on it. So if i gonna generate track i want to have it in mind, so it will ignore the "1". Basically a path finder, but not exactly.

I've heard that i can use a* algorithm but don't really know how to use it.

Comment: Is there any constraints on the path? Because there are infinite paths from a to b without any constraint...

Comment: You can use for loop to increment x and another for loop inside that to increment y. Printing both x and y in the inner loop would give you desired result.

Comment: @yidaohuuu Only map.cols wich looks like: 00001000111011001

Comment: As you said, you can solve this using the A* Search Algorithm, so [this](https://briangrinstead.com/blog/astar-search-algorithm-in-javascript/) JS implementation might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop & add the results to the array output:

```js
var a = {
  x: 21,
  y: 21
}

var b = {
  x: 26,
  y: 21
}

function generateTrack(a, b) {
  var maxX = a.x <= b.x ? b.x : a.x;
  var minX = a.x <= b.x ? a.x : b.x;
  var maxY = a.y <= b.y ? b.y : a.y;
  var minY = a.y <= b.y ? a.y : b.y;
  var coor = [];
  for( var i = minX; i <= maxX; i++) {
      for( var j = minY; j <= maxY; j++) {
        coor.push({'x' : i, 'y' : j});
  }
  }
  return coor;
}

var output = generateTrack(a, b);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if there are some object, that you cant walk on?
In my case its variable map.col which output "001101110011011" where "1" is a place where you can't walk on

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: This is a map, which is 32x32 each box, and whole map is 128x128 boxes, and there are some collisions on the map. which are set like this: map.col = "001100110011100", and you can't walk on object with "1" which is basically 1 32x32 grid

Comment: Can you edit the question & add the new input & the wanted output?

Comment: I've updated my question. Hope it's much cleaner now.